# How to concatenate multiple column values into one column in datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable with 3 columns( col1,col2,col3)
I have added an extra column with col4(Lets say).

Now My requirement is :

```
Col1 ||    col2 ||  col3  ||  col4

A          B        C         Col1-A;Col2-B;Col3-C
```

Basically, I want a concatenated values in the new column of the existing column name and values as demonstrated above. 
Hope my requirement is understood.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you know how to insert and retrieve values you can basically do a `String.Format("Col1-{0};Col2-{1};Col3-C{2}", Col1Val, Col2Val, Col3Val);` and insert it's value in Col4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
DataColumn newColumn;
newColumn = new DataColumn("col4");
newColumn.Expression =  string.Format("Col1\-{0};Col2\-{1};Col3\-{2}", col1, col2, col3);
scaleResponseData.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```